# Recursion - Euler 15

Tags: python-3.x

I am aware that there are published solutions to Euler 15. I have technically got a working solution (it yields the correct number) but when it print's the routes, it does so incorrectly

```
def legal_moves (row, column, grid):
    legal_moves = []
    if row != grid:
        legal_moves.append ([row+1,column])
    if column != grid:
        legal_moves.append ([row,column+1])
    if column == grid and row == grid:
        return False 
    return legal_moves

def find_route (row,column,grid, route):

    l_moves = legal_moves (row,column,grid)
    if l_moves == False:
        route.append ([row,column])
        list_routes.append (route)
        return
    else:
        route.append ([row,column])
        if len(l_moves) == 1:
            row = l_moves[0][0]
            column = l_moves[0][1]
            find_route (row,column,grid,route)
        if len(l_moves) ==2:
            row_a, column_a = l_moves[0][0], l_moves[0][1]
            row_b, column_b = l_moves[1][0], l_moves[1][1]
            find_route (row_a,column_a,grid,route)
            find_route (row_b,column_b,grid,route)

grid = int(input("Enter A for grid size AxA: "))
list_routes = []

find_route(0,0,grid, route = [])
for item in list_routes:
    print (item)
    print ()
```

I ran it for board size 2 (so input: grid = 2) and the terminal printed

```
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]

[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]

[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]

[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]

[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]

[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
```

I cannot work out why it line 1 does not just print:

```
[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]
```

and line 2:

```
[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2]
```

etc...
Please can someone help me understand why? 
Thanks

Comment: Use liberal application of print statements to check `list_routes` and other variables frequently throughout the running of the program. Find out where it first diverges from what you expect, and that will make it much easier to find the issue.

Comment: So it seems the issue is using the line route.append. for some reason the list doesn't assign itself differently to each recursive call. Why? Thanks